# Nvidia driver 430 crashes KUBUNTU 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, gpu-driver

I have recently installed Kubuntu 18.04 on my Acer laptop (MX150 gpu). I searched for the nvidia drivers listed using

```
ubuntu-drivers list
```

which listed

```
nvidia-driver-396
nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-driver-415
nvidia-driver-430
nvidia-driver-418
nvidia-driver-410
```

Elsewhere, in the driver manager, it says nvidia-driver-430 is recommended, so I select it and install. However, upon doing so, it crashes my Kubuntu. It doesn't let me turn off or open the settings (sends a crash notification)
Please help. It would be nice to be able to use 430 as I wish to try out the tensorflow2 gpu version. Since that is the primary goal, if you have any workaround which lets me do that, please share that hack.

Additional info about my installation:

```
Static hostname: konsole
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
          Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic                                                                                                                             
      Architecture: x86-64
```

```
Thu Jul  4 16:03:50 2019                                                                                                                                                
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                         
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.116                Driver Version: 390.116                   |                                                                                         
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+                                                                                         
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |                                                                                         
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    233MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       879      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            90MiB |
|    0      1327      G   kwin_x11                                      16MiB |
|    0      1336      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               1MiB |
|    0      1338      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                          89MiB |
|    0      1531      G   ...quest-channel-token=7993052452492937676    34MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

*Using 16.04 LTS here, running nvidia binary driver 384.130 without problems.*

Before switching driver, uninstall any separately downloaded nvidia driver.
You might need to run the uninstall from the recovery console and Reboot.

Find and open "System settings" (In the left side panel on 16.04)
then goto "Software and updates" and find the /Additional drivers\ -tab.

Select the proprietary driver, I'd recommend to try a version that reads "tested".

For running GPU stuff, you might need to install "cuda" also...
Open a shell (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) then type `sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> a couple times(?) to find a version compatible to the driver above (continue typing after the items are shown to select one). There might be only one... (`nvidia-cuda-toolkit` is what I see in 16.04)